# Trying to JSON.parse() a JSON array returned from df.to_json(), but running into SyntaxErrors

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am building a web app with Flask that takes the result from a merge function and calls it in Javascript.
Below is my working merge function. Printing df.to_json(orient="records") **always** prints a valid JSON array of objects, formatted as [{...}, {...}, ..., {...}, {...}].

```
def createNewDataList(files, variables):
    #merge stuff (everything works fine here)
    return df.to_json(orient="records")
```

This is my Flask script for calling the function:

```
@app.route('/createDf/', methods=['POST', "GET"])
def create_df():
    new_df = data_merger.createNewDataList(dc, vc) # datasetChooser, variableChooser
    response = {
        'message': 'data processing successful',
        'status': 200,
        'new_df': new_df
    }
    return response
```

This is what I am using to in Javascript to get the result from create_df().

```
async function retrieveJSON() {
    var myData = [];

    try {
        const response = await fetch('createDf'); // issues a GET request by default
        const data = await response.json(); // data becomes the response from create_df(), which is { 'message': 'data processing successful', 'status': 200, 'new_df': new_df }
        // access the new_df data from the response
        const new_df = data.new_df; // this js constant is set to the new_df output from the response, which is a JSON array
        // populate myData with new_df
        myData = JSON.parse(new_df);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('error processing data:', error);
    }
    return myData;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that most times (for every dataframe I'm using and for <20 variables), everything runs smoothly, and the Javascript function returns the expected result. However, if I have too many variables, the Javascript function returns a "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input".

Apparently, the new_df in create_df() becomes an empty string after being called using fetch('createDf'), but testing print(new_df[-100:]) in createDf() returns the last one hundred characters of the expected JSON string.

Comment: Can you figure out roughly where the threshold is (in bytes) where it starts to fail? And is the behavior the same across browsers?

Comment: This `const data = await response.json();` already parses the response.  You shouldn’t (TM) need to additionally parse new_df.  Unless it was encoded twice, which is usually a mistake.

Comment: I haven't fixed it, but I'm thinking I'm just going to work around it. It's an outer-join, so the length is the same if I select variables from every dataset, and I can just manually change some things after I turn it into a csv file. (For now, I believe the maximum threshold is about 550 MB--about 16 variables; the json is over a million objects long.)